# Using Reverse Tunnel from Proxy Server in Ansible

Tags: ssh, ansible

I have two things that I'm able to do separately but would like to combine into a single step so I can automate it with Ansible.

- Host A is my own laptop that cannot directly access C
- Host B is a server with internet access that can access C. It is running `squid`
- Host C which has no internet access

I can manually SSH to B and set up a reverse tunnel when I SSH to C. This allows C to have internet access if I set up `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in the environment.

I can also use Ansible to connect to Host C from Host A via the proxy Host B. However so far whenever I do this host C has no internet access as the reverse tunnel isn't set up.

So I'm able to get close to my goal of running Ansible jobs on C while enabling internet access with a reverse tunnel from B, but I can't combine these two steps. So far I have

```
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=ERROR -o ProxyCommand="ssh -p 22 -W %h:%p -q admin@HOST_B"'
ansible_ssh_extra_args="-R 3129:localhost:3128"
```

This works to connect to C, but I cannot access the internet. I'm guessing the `ansible_ssh_extra_args` is run on my host machine, when really I want to be run from the proxy server B when connecting to B.

I've tried putting the `-R 3129:localhost:3128` in a few different places but without success. If I manually connect to B and run the reverse proxy command before running the Ansible task (which tests pinging Google) it works as expected.

How can I tell Ansible to use a reverse tunnel from the proxy server when connecting to C?

Comment: To get a better understanding of your description, does "_I can also use Ansible to connect to Host C from Host A via the proxy Host B. However so far whenever I do this host C has no internet access as the reverse tunnel isn't set up. So I'm able to get close to my goal of running Ansible jobs on C while enabling internet access with a reverse tunnel from B_" mean that you can actually connect with Ansible from A to C, transfer small Python packages over, start the execution there, but don't get the output channel back? Therefore you like to setup the reverse tunnel on a global level?

Comment: I can connect to it, like the ansible ping command works. But it doesn't set up the reverse tunnel from B -> C when I do this so when I do something like run a playbook (`ansible.builtin.uri`) that tries to connect to the internet it fails

Comment: "_like the ansible ping command works_", that's good information. So the communication is working in two ways. How about setting `environment` for `uri` module as shown in the answer? Does it improve the behavior?

Answer (score 1):

According your description

> *This allows C to have internet access if I set up `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in the environment.*

I understand that (only) for tasks which will require internet access (annot. and which might be very few), you need probably just to [set the remote environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) via

```yaml
- name: Update all packages
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
  environment:
    http_proxy: http://localhost:3128
    https_proxy: http://localhost:3128
```

Please consider that Ansible bases on [Task execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#task-execution). For each task a connection will be made and a small package for remote execution transferred.

Comment: The package update is the one I'm actually trying to get working :-) I have the `http_proxy` set on the target server (C) and have also tried passing them via the `environment` for the job. However it always fails because I can't configure it to create the reverse tunnel _as part of the playbook execution_. If I manually SSH to B and create the reverse tunnel to C then it works.

Comment: I see, that I can't probably debug because of the lack of testing environment. In my environment I am using an other channel to go back to the internet. It is just the `cntlm` module that makes a connection to an other proxy and can also act as a forwarder. So I never have to deal with huge complexity. And simply setting the remote environment and localhost:3128 is just enough.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help anyway. I guess the difficult part is that I can pass arguments to the SSH command from A -> B using stuff like `ansible_ssh_extra_args`, and I tell Ansible to use B as a proxy from B -> C with `ansible_ssh_common_args='-J admin@B'` (jump server) but I can't seem to find a way to pass arguments to use when executing SSH from B -> C (i.e. to make it a reverse tunnel). I've tried with `~/.ssh/config` on B too which again works manually but seems to be ignored by Ansible. Thanks for your help, maybe the solution will just have to be manually setting up rev tunnel